# Regarding TLS termination at application load balancer AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, ssl, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I have application in container , which runs on protocol HTTP with port 1429. Conainer is deployed in AWS EKS. I have conferred the ALB with certificate. Listener port is HTTPS and port 443.
I need to terminate TLS at ALB and forward request http to 1429.
I configured ingress target port as 1429.
I am getting target TLS Negotiation Error in cloud watch metrics.
Any suggestions on this.

Answer (score 1):

I would double check that the target group protocol is set to HTTP. Seeing as your application is deployed to EKS you could port-forward to the port in question and make a HTTP curl request to ensure that no TLS errors are thrown and that the request is handled as expected.

Comment: we can not have target group protocol set to HTTP as per our ORG rules.
How to  terminate it in ingress controller?